# ng-include fragment from a template

Tags: angularjs

I have a external template file  which  has more than one fragment, In my main page I want to include a fragment from this template , could not figure out how, Please advice.
Plunker link  http://plnkr.co/edit/p6d0dECPji5kwh9xFuVy?p=preview

example of what I need

```
<div  ng-include ="'template1.html#sectionOne'"></div>
```

I tried loading template using jquery and add it to $templateCache  it did not work please advice.

```
app.run(function($templateCache,$http) {
    $http.get('template1.html').success(function(template){
        console.log(' sectionOne Template '+ $(template).filter('#sectionOne').html());
        $templateCache.put('sectionOne.html',$(template).filter('#sectionOne').html());
        console.log(' sectionOne Template from cache '+$templateCache.get('sectionOne.html'));
    }).error(function () {

    });
});


<div  ng-include ="'sectionOne.html'"></div>
```

below is my code  new plunker link   http://plnkr.co/edit/p6d0dECPji5kwh9xFuVy?p=preview

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.17" data-semver="1.2.17" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.0.1" data-semver="2.0.1" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">


    <div ng-include="'tempate1.hml'"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var app=angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.run(function($templateCache,$http) {
        $http.get('ddComponent.html').success(function(template){
            $templateCache.put('template1.html',$(template).filter('#template1').html());
            $templateCache.put('template2.html',$(template).filter('#template2').html());
            $templateCache.put('template3.html',$(template).filter('#template3').html());

            console.log($templateCache.get('template1.html'));
            console.log($templateCache.get('template2.html'));
            console.log($templateCache.get('template3.html'));
        }).error(function () {
            alert('error');
        });
    });
</script>




  </body>

</html>
```

code for  ddComponent.html

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template3">
    <div >
            Content for template 3
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="template1">
        <div>
            Content for template1
        </div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="template2">
    <div>
         Content for template 2
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: You can't include a fragment of a template with `ngInclude`.

Comment: I need advice on manually loading the template and putting in the   $templateCache , myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('template1SectionOne.html', loadSectionOne using jquery);
});  can we do something like this?

Comment: I think yes. Why not...?

Comment: I tried loading the partial template added it to $templateCache   but ng-include is not displaying the template  updated the plunker.  app.run(function($templateCache,$http) {
    $http.get('template1.html').success(function(template){
        console.log(' sectionOne Template '+ $(template).filter('#sectionOne').html());
        $templateCache.put('sectionOne.html',$(template).filter('#sectionOne').html());
        console.log(' sectionOne Template from cache '+$templateCache.get('sectionOne.html'));
    }).error(function () {

    });
});

Comment: How about an updated plunkr ?

Comment: Link for updated plunker http://plnkr.co/SE3HiRYltQWcWU99k5Uc

Comment: Plunkr returns an HTML document even if the requested URL does not exist. I don't think your approach will be easy to work with. You might manage to device a working verison of it, but I don't think it will be worth the trouble. Why use a more straight-forward approach (retrieving the sections as separate templates, using `<script>` tempaltes etc) ?

Comment: added new plnkr link  http://plnkr.co/edit/p6d0dECPji5kwh9xFuVy?p=preview also code in the post.

Comment: Did you take a look at my answer below ? Did it work for you ?

Comment: I understand why it was not working and your suggestion, thank  you so much, is there any way I can prolong run method till init service loads everything, than controller knowing about the init service?

Comment: Now that I am thinking this over, maybe you can get the behaviour you want if you use `ngRoute` (or `ui-router`).

Comment: Thanks,I will check that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a service for loading the HTML file, extracting the templates (using jQuery) and storing them in `$templateCache`.
You can then use this service in a controller to set the value of a variable bound to `ngInclude` in the view:

```
<!-- In the VIEW -->
<div ng-include="tmpl1"></div>

/* In the CONTROLLER */
.controller('SomeCtrl', function SomeCtrl($scope, TemplateLoader) {
  TemplateLoader.ready.then(function () {
    $scope.tmpl1 = 'template1.html';
  });
})

/* In the SERVICE */
.service('TemplateLoader', function TemplateLoader($http, $templateCache) {
  this.ready = $http.get('ddComponent.html').then(function (response) {
    var $template = $(response.data);
    $templateCache.put('template1.html', $template.filter('#template1').html());
    $templateCache.put('template2.html', $template.filter('#template2').html());
    $templateCache.put('template3.html', $template.filter('#template3').html());
  }).catch(function () {
    alert('Error !');
  });
});
```

---

See, also, this **[modified demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/iCgqDBQnnpkRaZNqXRwf?p=preview)**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to load a fragment from a html file with angularJS with the ngInclude directive. Your best bet would be to use inline scripts like this ([plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/u5E7lzrFqTN8HESQv7yy?p=preview)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>

  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.17" data-semver="1.2.17" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>

  <script type='text/ng-template' id="tpl1.html">
    <div>Template 1 </div> 
  </script>

  <script type='text/ng-template' id="tpl2.html">
    <div>Template 2 </div> 
  </script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="testCtrl">



  <div ng-include src="'tpl1.html'"></div>

</body>

</html>
```